# How to programmatically get windows search history?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, search

How to get the windows search history and use it in my program? For example I write ".doc" in windows search bar. Now I want in my program to find out from somewhere, that I searched for ".doc" in my system (not web).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Windows Search Bar". Note that this is an area in which there's significant change between Windows versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's an API for it, but if you do a Windows search for an unlikely string, say "zxcvbnm", then search the registry for it, then on XP you can see it under one of the folders in:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Search\ACMru
```

along with the rest of your recent search strings. I imagine this registry location may change between Windows versions though.

If you're targetting Windows 7 then [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965362.aspx) looks like a good starting point.